# iconv - Transliterate if possible, otherwise leave unconverted

Tags: bash, utf-8, iconv

Consider the following example line of text:

> `α Arietis, called Hamal, is the brightest star in Aries. Its traditional name is derived from the Arabic word for “lamb” or “head of the ram” (ras al-hamal).`

It has three different UTF-8 characters, the `α`, a left smart quote, and a right smart quote.

My goal is to transliterate as much as possible from UTF-8 to regular ASCII, but leave any non-convertible characters as-is.  (In the above sample text, the smart quotes can be transliterated to `"`, but the `α` cannot.)

My current command is:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT < iconv.sample
```

However, it fails to convert the `α` and terminates with `iconv: (stdin):1:0: cannot convert`.
If I add `//IGNORE` to the target or use the `-c` option, it drops the `α` altogether.

How can I transliterate if possible, but fallback to the original input character if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible when using `iconv`, as the output encoding will have to be conformed to (that is, if you specify `ASCII`, it's only going to spit out `ASCII`, no matter what).

If you have [uconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uconv) available, you can specify transliteration operations away from output encoding:

```
uconv -f "UTF-8" -t "UTF-8" -x "Latin-ASCII"
```

As an example:

```
$ echo "α Arietis “head of the ram”" | uconv -f "UTF-8" -t "UTF-8" -x "Latin-ASCII"
α Arietis "head of the ram"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!  I had no idea uconv was even a utility.

Comment: I'm a bit late revisiting this, but it appears that `Latin-ASCII` has a bad habit of converting accented characters to unaccented ASCII.  The correct transliteration seems to be `-x ':: [[:Punctuation:][:Symbol:]] Latin-ASCII;'`.  This only applies the `Latin-ASCII` transform to punctuation and symbols.